# Creating x64 Installer for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, 64-bit

I am trying to use Visual Studio Installer to create an installer for my project. It's x64 project but I keep getting a compatibility error:

Error   1   targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

I tried editing the platform of the setup project but it's greyed out!!

What am I to do?

I realized my Visual Studio 2013 is in the x86 Windows folder? ANy relation to what I am facing?

THanks all

Comment: I have created a x64 project alright.. Even the exe file is in the x64 folder within the project. And I am sorry but I can't seem to find the "prefer 32-bit" t check it, where is it?? In the project properties?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what was wrong but in case someone encounters this, the InstallShield LE worked smoothly...

Comment: I'd guess that you are importing a VS project that is building x64 code and the VS installer is trying to tell you that you can't install it on an x86 system. It doesn't matter what your toll runs on - you can generated 64-bit stuff with 32-bit code.